# Phonegap / Cordova: socialsharing plugin not working

Tags: javascript, cordova

I included the socialsharing plugin into config.xml as:

```
<gap:plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing" />
```

(using cordova v. 3.3.1)

In my html I include:

```
<script src="phonegap.js"></script>  
 or
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Now when calling:

```
function shareReport() {
window.plugins.socialsharing.share(mytext);
}
```

by a button:

```
onclick="shareReport()"
```

the program stops suddenly and closes down.
("mytext" is a global variable that is populated with a text string containing html tags - this variable has a value at this point)

Any suggestions what is going wrong ?

Thank you in advance,
Chris

Comment: does it give any clues in the console log?

Comment: what platform you currently use?

Answer (score 3):

Social sharing Plugin will work as you expected so it looks like you missed something,
Check your XML for below fields,

```
<!-- for iOS -->
<feature name="SocialSharing">
  <param name="ios-package" value="SocialSharing" />
</feature>
<!-- for Android -->
<feature name="SocialSharing">
  <param name="android-package" value="nl.xservices.plugins.SocialSharing" />
</feature>
<!-- for Windows Phone -->
<feature name="SocialSharing">
  <param name="wp-package" value="SocialSharing"/>
</feature>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Check your Script,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/SocialSharing.js"></script>
```

This is must,

```
<gap:plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing" version="4.0" />
```

Try a test drive,

```
<button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.canShareVia('com.apple.social.facebook', 'msg', null, null, null, function(e){alert(e)}, function(e){alert(e)})">is facebook available on iOS?</button>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot - nevertheless in the docu it's mentioned that for phonegap use, it's not necessary to include anything into the html, only add one line into the xml (<gap:plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing" /> ) as you said. Strangely enough, it USED to work for me before, seems an update of the plugin isnt working anymore ? Someone has the same experience ?

Comment: Thanks for the update.. We have various issues while updating.. Its good to use recommended options with latest version.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I figured it out.
You were right, the SocialSharing plugin works simply by including the line

```
<gap:plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing" />
```

into config.xml.
My problem came from unaccepted characters in the text that I sent for sharing which caused the program crash.
Thanks for every help !